# Python match whitespaces

Tags: python

Im trying to remove multiple white-spaces in a string. I've read about regular expressions in python langauge and i've tried to make it match all white-sapces in the string, but no success. The `return msg` part returns empty:

**CODE**

```
import re

def correct(string):
    msg = ""
    fmatch = re.match(r'\s', string, re.I|re.L)
    if fmatch:
        msg = fmatch.group
    return msg

print correct("This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this task, you can instead replace consecutive whitespaces with a single space character, for example, using `re.sub`.
Example:

```
import re

def correct(string):
    fmatch = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', string)
    return fmatch

print correct("This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!")
```

The output will be:

```
This is very funny and cool.Indeed!
```

Comment: Can I add another expression to find . (dots) ? and replace them with .+space

Comment: @IdontReallywolf so you want `"."` to be replaced with `". "`? Yes, you can, in a similar fashion

Comment: do I have to create a new line or can the expression be added in the current line ?.

Comment: You have to make another `sub` call in a different line

Comment: @IdontReallywolf, you can do it this way: `re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s.replace('.', '. '))`, where `s` is your string. PS don't use reserved words like `string`, `list`, `dict`, etc. as a name for your variables - this will help to avoid problems in future.

Comment: @MaxU `string` is completely safe to use, as the built-in constructor is called `str`, so `string` variable name is not reserved

Comment: @Leva7, what about `string` module? How would you call for instance `string.ascii_letters` if you have overwritten `string` with your variable?

Comment: @MaxU That's a good point, but since he's not using it, in this case it's safe

Answer (score 2):

`re.match` matches only at the beginning of the string. You need to use `re.search` instead.

Comment: So i've changed it to `re.search(r'\s', string, re.I|re.L)` and got this msg: **<built-in method group of _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b7fb9f0>**

Comment: Yes, `group` is a method, you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code helps you?

```
import re

def correct(string):
    return " ".join(re.split(' *', string))
```

Answer (score 0):

One line no direct import

```
ss= "This is very funny and cool.Indeed!"
ss.replace(" ", "  ")
#ss.replace(" ", " "*2) 

#'This  is  very  funny  and  cool.Indeed!'
```

Or,  as the question states:

```
ss= "This is very funny and cool.Indeed!"
ss.replace(" ", "")

#'Thisisveryfunnyandcool.Indeed!'
```